# Apply datatables filtering to only one table

Tags: jquery, datatable

I'm using custom filtering per class name. I also have two different dataTables on my page, but it seems that the filter I'm adding applies to both dataTables. I would like to specify on which one it actually applies to.

```
$.fn.dataTableExt.afnFiltering.push(function (oSettings, aData, iDataIndex) {
  var myRowClasses = oSettings.aoData[iDataIndex].nTr.className.split(" ");
  if($("#subplayers").is(":checked")) {
    return myRowClasses.indexOf('insub') > -1;
  } else {
    return myRowClasses.indexOf('allplayers') > -1;
  }         
});
```

This filter applies to both tables (table 1 with it `tabledata`and table 2 with id `tabledata2`). How can I modify this code in order for it to work only on table 1?

Table code:

```
var table = $('#tabledata').DataTable({
  'fnCreatedRow': function (nRow, aData, iDataIndex) {
    $(nRow).attr('id', 'col' + iDataIndex+'_filter');
    if (initatedTable){
      $(nRow).addClass("insub");
      $(nRow).addClass("allplayers");
    }
  }
});

var table2 = $('#tabledata2').DataTable({
  'fnCreatedRow': function (nRow, aData, iDataIndex) {
    $(nRow).attr('id', 'col' + iDataIndex+'_filter');
   }
});
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to add an if check to your filter function like this;

```
$.fn.dataTableExt.afnFiltering.push(function (oSettings, aData, iDataIndex) {
  if (settings.nTable.id === 'tabledata') {
     // filter example
  }
  else {
    // ...
  }        
});
```

in this example, `if (settings.nTable.id === 'tabledata')` line will do the trick.

Comment: Also, if you do not want any custom filtering for other tables, else needs *return true;*